# ObjectBox Java sometimes throws error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.text.Charsets

Tags: java, objectbox

Sometimes when i run the application that using ObjectBox java with no kotlin coding, java throws this error. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.text.Charsets

```
dependencies {
    // Optional: include all native libraries for distribution
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-linux:$objectboxVersion"
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-macos:$objectboxVersion"
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-windows:$objectboxVersion"

}

apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
```

But run again the error gone and the application started normally... anything wrong? do i need to include kotlin lib in my gradle build manually? or its caused by the ide is building the project so get error on the first run its confusing here. I am using IntelliJ, Gradle,ObjectBox 2.8.1,Java 1.8

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-109" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/text/Charsets
    at io.objectbox.reporting.BasicBuildTracker.sendEvent(BasicBuildTracker.kt:166)
    at io.objectbox.reporting.BasicBuildTracker$sendEventAsync$1.run(BasicBuildTracker.kt:143)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.text.Charsets
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.text.Charsets

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.text.Charsets

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.text.Charsets
```

Comment: You need to put the whole stack trace of the error in your question.

Comment: added full stacktrace

Comment: Can you please try 2.8.0 and see if this version runs fine?

Comment: 2.8.0 seems to be working fine... didn't see the error after few runs